# Grid box displaying wrong while calling HTML data using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, css-grid

I have designed a grid using HTML and CSS. When the user clicks the grid, I display another grid using PHP and AJAX.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.showme', function() {

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var num = $(this).attr("class");
    var poststr = "request=" + num + "&moreinfo=" + id;
    $.ajax({enter code here
      url: "http://kiranasaman.com/mobiledesign/testme.php",
      cache: 0,
      data: poststr,
      success: function(result) {
        document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML = result;
      }
    });
  });
});
```

```css
main {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 1em auto;
  padding: 1em 2em;
  color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(204, 204, 204, .7);
  border: .07em solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: .5em;
}

button {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 100%;
  border-radius: 1em;
  border: .1em solid #333;
  padding: 1em;
  width: 8em;
  margin: .25em;
  width: 23%;
}

button strong {
  display: block;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  line-height: 1.35;
  width: 1.5em;
  height: 1.5em;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 200%;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: .1em solid #fff;
}

button:hover,
button:focus {
  background-color: #060;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1em rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
}

.gridmine {
  display: -ms-grid;
  -ms-grid-columns: auto 1fr;
  -ms-grid-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: auto minmax(min-content, 1fr) auto;
}

.title {
  -ms-grid-column: 1;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.title1 {
  ms-grid-column: 2;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.title2 {
  ms-grid-column: 3;
  -ms-grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 3;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.gridmine button {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.gridmine button:hover {
  background-color: #73090D;
}

.gridmine .soman {
  height: 200px;
  font-size: 24px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>

  <h2 style="font-size:28px;">Shop by Category</h2>
  <div class="gridmine" id="grid">
    <div class="soman title">
      <button class='request_1 showme' id='rating_1' style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);">

      <h3>  Rice, Grains &amp; Flours</h3>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="soman title1">
      <button style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9a9e  0%, #fad0c4 100%);">

         <h3>Dals, Pulses &amp; Seeds</h3>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="soman title2">
      <button style="background: linear-gradient(to right, #a1c4fd  0%, #c2e9fb 100%);">
        <h3>Sugar &amp; Salts</h3>
      </button>
    </div>

  </div>
</main>
```

When the user clicks the box, I am fetching data using AJAX and PHP and displaying it replacing the same grid.

PHP code:

```html
<?php
  $request_id = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_REQUEST['request']);
  $request_moreinfo = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/","",$_REQUEST['moreinfo']);

  if($request_id=="1")
  {
      echo "<div id='grids' class='gridmine'>
        <div class='soman titles'>
          <button class='request_2 seeme' id='rating_2' style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);'>

          <h3>  Rice</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='soman title1s'>
          <button style='background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9a9e  0%, #fad0c4 100%);'>

             <h3>Grains</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='soman title2s'>
          <button style='background: linear-gradient(to right, #a1c4fd  0%, #c2e9fb 100%);'>
            <h3>Flours</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
</div>";
  }
  ?>
```

I am using the same class for everything in both grids. The first grid is properly being displayed, but the second grid, which is coming from the AJAX PHP request, is not displaying properly as the first, its width is smaller.

Can anyone please tell me what could be wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the `innerHTML` of `#grid` to be what is essentially the same element, container included. If you remove the container it should work:

```
echo "
        <div class='soman titles'>
          <button class='request_2 seeme' id='rating_2' style='background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #cc99ff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);'>

          <h3>  Rice</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='soman title1s'>
          <button style='background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff9a9e  0%, #fad0c4 100%);'>

             <h3>Grains</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class='soman title2s'>
          <button style='background: linear-gradient(to right, #a1c4fd  0%, #c2e9fb 100%);'>
            <h3>Flours</h3>
          </button>
        </div>
";
```

Then it will just replace it with the three `div` elements with buttons in.